# sql server update field if condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, alter

i'm working on a project where i have to alter a tables defenition but i need to keep the data there's already there and i don't know how to accomplish this.

the actual table struct is as follows

```
[IDDocumento (int)]
[IDTipoDocumento (int)]
[IDEntidade (int)]
[Data (datetime)]
[Designacao (varchar 100)]
[TotalIliquido (money)]
[TotalImposto (money)]
[TotalRetencoes (money)]
[TotalLiquido (money)]
[Anulado (bit)]
```

what i need to do here is to drop the 'Anulado' column and add 3 new columns, maintaining the stored data, and giving a value to one of the new columns if 'Anulado' was TRUE

what i have is

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Documentos
ADD
IDEstadoDocumento int null,
DataVencimento datetime null,
ValorAberto decimal(18,5) not null CONSTRAINT DF_Documentos_ValorAberto DEFAULT 0;

//HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO CHECK IF 'ANULADO' IS TRUE OR NOT AND CHANGE 'IDEstadoDOCUMENTO' TO 3 WHEN IT IS

ALTER TABLE dbo.Documentos
DROP COLUMN Anulado;
```

How am i suposed to do this?

Comment: Do you need to use pure sql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simple update should suffice

```
UPDATE dbo.Documentos SET IDEstadoDocumento = 3 WHERE Anulado = 1
```

Comment: oh my... of course! lol not thinking straigth this morning :D thanks